# HTML modal dialog overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm working on a website, which will present a modal dialog when a button was clicked. I would want the background to not be scroll-able however the dialog is scroll-able, here is my code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLPpA/). I'm thinking the dialog should be embedded inside another div which's `overflow` is set to `auto` however that didn't work. Any solutions.?

UPDATE
[image]

From this image, I want the red area to be scrollable while keeping the green area not scrollable.

Comment: Not sure what the problems is, everything seems to look fine on my screen.

Comment: I looked at the JSFiddle but I'm a bit confused still what you are aiming to accomplish.  I'm looking at this on Google Chrome and the content is scrollable like it should be inside the dialog.  Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: So you just want the message div to not be scrollable?

Comment: @Xero Thank you guys for trying to help me out! I've updated the question and added an image to describe the problem more accurately, thanks!

Comment: @user1506980 Thank you guys for trying to help me out! I've updated the question and added an image to describe the problem more accurately, thanks!

Comment: @Matthew Check this out and see if it's the same idea (with the scroll on top but not on background thing).  If so, I'll disect the useful parts for you and post it here.  http://jsfiddle.net/Ss2nq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I was able to get the functionality you're trying to achieve. It seems like what's making this difficult for you is you're trying to have one scrollbar span multiple elements on the page and there's no element in the markup to apply that CSS rule to. Just wrap all the elements you want to be scrollable in a container and set that container to `overflow: auto` (and remove the overflow rule from the other elements).

**Edit**

Based on the comments below I've updated the fiddle. Same idea as before, but now the scrollable wrapper is the body itself. Only gotcha here is your CSS on the dialog was `position:fixed`, but it stands to reason you won't be able to scroll through content that is positioned relative to the viewport.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLPpA/10/)

Comment: This is pretty much what I'd do, except I'd add the scroll to a container around the modal, so the modal doesn't scroll, and you are able to scroll on the page around the modal.

Comment: Hi @user1506980, thank you for the suggestion, I reviewed the fiddle you mentioned however that isn't quite what i want, i wanted the whole red area to scroll instead of just the content within it, is there any ways i can implement that? Thanks!

Comment: @chad that is what I would really want to achieve, can you post an answer with the fiddle you used? Thanks!

Comment: @Matthew Okay, the fiddle has been updated. Let me know if this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: @Matthew I was out at lunch-- looks like he beat me to it. Let me know if you need anything else done though.

Comment: @user1506980 this is very close to what i was looking for! however i would want the dialog to be on top of the other components... right now it is above the components... can you please revise that part? :p thank you so much!

Comment: @Chad Taking a late lunch is key

Comment: @Matthew I should have done that in the first place =D. Just updated the dialog to be position absolute instead of relative.

Comment: @user1506980 12:30 is not late!

Answer (score 0):

I understood that the issue is how to make the header of the modal dialog extend vertically with a scrollbar instead the whole thing.

If that is the case, the overflow approach is the right one; however, overflow itself does not do the trick alone. Overflow likes having friends like width and height around :)

So, in your case, you want a vertical overflow - overflow-y therefore.

And overflow-y needs a height to work. And the height of your header probably will be 55px (this is something you have to decide).

So. Add CSS to the title:

```
#dialog #title {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 55px;

}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HectorWasHere/6gFSV/1/